# Linq, how get properly string with convert

Tags: c#, linq, valueconverter

I have got problem with getting string from the file via linq.

**My file is:**

```
    LANG_FORM="nnd documents acceptance"
%>
            Response.Write "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=javascript>alert('" & LN("KtśćóŻ") & "');</SCRIPT>"
```

it is part of asp file but now it is doesn't matter.

I have to get value in LN function.
**I write linq synatx like:**

```
var LN = from place in File.ReadAllLines(item.file)
                                         where Regex.IsMatch(place, pattern)
                                         select new { place };
```

**In debug view i have non properly output:**

```
{ place =           Response.Write "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=javascript>alert('" & LN("Kt���") & "');</SCRIPT>" }
```

My question is, how prepare linq syntax to get output properly (they are polish letters)?

Comment: You said that you want the value in `LN` function. You mean, you need `"KtśćóŻ"`? What is your regex pattern? The problem lies in your regex pattern, not the LINQ query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think encoding is wrong.

Try [File.ReadAllLines(String, Encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsy4fhsa.aspx).

```
var LN = from place in File.ReadAllLines(item.file, Encoding.UTF8)
                                         where Regex.IsMatch(place, pattern)
                                         select new { place };
```

You can use desired encoding, not only `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: var LN = from place in File.ReadAllLines(item.file, Encoding.Default)
                                         where Regex.IsMatch(place, pattern)
                                         select new { place }; this is correct code, for me worked good. To MD.Unicorn: Maybe I not clerly said, I set LN value when i get place properly, now is good, thank's.